# passing a unique variable inbetween url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i have a software which passed a unique id to the url of my clients but limitation of my software is that is passes the unique id in the end of the url and sometimes link are too long and we want to pass id inbetween the url like www.zyx.com?id=**i want to pass id here in between** &jsabdkhbdf&sdkjbahdb&kjdsbkfbskdb&pid=jdndhf

i have seeen a software where is you to pass id in between you type like this **?id=[%id%]**  where every in url i type this parameter will pass there idk how its hapenning there pls help pasting the code

```
<?php  require_once("session.php" );?>

<?php include("header.php"); require_once("dbcon.php");?>

<div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
    <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
            <li class="sidebar-search">
                <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </button>
                </span>
                </div>


            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Dashboard</a><br>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> Survey<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                    <li>
                        <a href="new_survey.php">New Survey</a>
                        <a href="add_client.php">Add Clients</a>
                        <a href="client_list.php">Clients List</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="survey_list.php" class="alert alert-success">Survey List</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
                <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
            </li><br>
            <li>
                <a href="add_vendor.php"><i class="fa fa-table fa-fw"></i>Add Vendor</a>
                <a href="vendor_list.php">Vendor List</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
</div>
<!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
<nav>
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8  ">
            <h1 class="page-header">Dashboard</h1>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <i class="fa fa-check-circle fa-5x"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                            <?php  
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(status) as count from new_survey WHERE Status LIKE 'open%'";
       $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc() )
         echo "<div class='huge'>{$rows['count']}</div>";
        ?>
                            <div>Surveys Completed</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        <span class="pull-left">View Details</span>
                        <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-green">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-5x"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                            <div class="huge">New</div>
                            <div>Survey</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href="new_survey.php">
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        <span class="pull-left">Create New Survey</span>
                        <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-yellow">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <i class="fa fa-ban fa-5x"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                            <?php  

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(status) as count from new_survey WHERE Status LIKE 'close%'";
       $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc() )
         echo "<div class='huge'>{$rows['count']}</div>";
        ?>
                            <div>InCompleted Surveys</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        <span class="pull-left">View Details</span>
                        <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-red">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <i class="fa fa-support fa-5x"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                            <?php  
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(status) as count from new_survey WHERE Status LIKE 'invoice%'";
       $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc() )
         echo "<div class='huge'>{$rows['count']}</div>";
        ?>
                            <div>Invoiced Surveys</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        <span class="pull-left">View Details</span>
                        <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Survey List
        </div>

    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="100%" border="1">
  <thead><tr>
    <th>Survey ID</th>
    <th>Client Name</th>
    <th>Survey Name</th>
      <th>Client Live URL</th>
      <th>Client Test URL</th>
      <th>Completed</th>
      <th>InCompleted</th>
      <th>Quota Full</th>
      <th>Time Period</th>
      <th>Creation Date</th>
      <th>End Date</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Edit</th>


  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<?php 
**this is unique parameter**
**$a = bin2hex(random_bytes(10));**


$sql = "SELECT * from new_survey where survey_id order by survey_id desc";
       $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "  <td>{$rows['survey_id']}</td>";
            echo "  <td>{$rows['client_name']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$rows['survey_name']}</td>";

here it is passing when fetching the url from database onclick of link


        **echo "<td> <a href=". $rows['client_live_url']  .  urlencode($a) . "&s_id=" . $rows['survey_id'] . " target='_blank'> Click Here </a></td>";**
        echo "<td> <a href=". $rows['client_test_url']  .  urlencode($a) ."> Click Here </a></td>";
        echo"    <td>{$rows['completed']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$rows['incompleted']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$rows['quota_full']}</td>";
        echo" <td>{$rows['time_period']}</td>";
        echo" <td>{$rows['creation_date']}</td>";
        echo"     <td>{$rows['end_date']}</td>";
        echo"     <td>{$rows['status']}</td>";
        echo"     <td><a href=\"edit_survey.php?id={$rows['survey_id']}\">Edit</td>";
        echo     "</tr>";      
    }
$conn->close();


?>


        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>





</div>

</div>
</div>




<!-- /#page-wrapper -->
<div class="panel-footer">
    <div class="text-center">
        <?php echo date('Y'); ?>, &copy;
        <?php echo "$copyright"; ?>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- /#wrapper -->

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="./vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="./vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="./vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

<!-- Morris Charts JavaScript -->
<script src="./vendor/raphael/raphael.min.js"></script>
<script src="./vendor/morrisjs/morris.min.js"></script>
<script src="./data/morris-data.js"></script>

<!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
<script src="./dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why is javascript, jquery, and ajax tagged here, your problem doesn't seem to be involving any of those? What do you mean by the link is too long? You have a bunch of code here what part actually deals with your problem?

Comment: if the url is www.zyx.com?id=here id will come here &jsabdkhbdf&sdkjbahdb&kjdsbkfbskdb&pid=jdndhf how i will pass the parameter in front end using input box

Comment: show us the main part from where that url generated.

Comment: **echo "<td> <a href=". $rows['client_live_url']  .  urlencode($a) . "&s_id=" . $rows['survey_id'] . " target='_blank'> Click Here </a></td>";**

Comment: If the id contains characters such as '&' which is used to separate url parameters, then you can encode the id using the urlencode() function

Comment: Please give an example of the actual url and and how you want this url to be